# How to represent and program relationships between people, items etc. in Java game

Tags: java

I'm going to be developing a game which will be simulating an environment of people interacting with each other and the goal of the game will be to become to rise to the top by doing activities, buying weapons, items, etc.. There will be a lot of names for the items and simulated people, and i was wondering how i could store and retrieve such information. Could i use something like XML or any other related language to do it? I will be developing this using java btw

Thanks.

Comment: In a database of some sort...?

Comment: This question will likely get closed as it is not appropriate for this site.  A database is probably the way to go, rather than XML.  I'd also recommend looking into Unity3d if you don't _have_ to use java.

Comment: It's unusually general but honestly it's a fair question.  "What sort of technology makes sense to store the relationship between people?"  The question is just novice, it's not asking for a shopping list etc.

Comment: More generally, for game development questions, you should ask here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You'll almost certainly want a relational database here.  I think MySQL is the easiest to learn/get started with/set up but I'd definitely be curious if there is a more "out of the box" option.

Comment: I would say Mysql or another RDBMS with a network layer if the database is intended to run on a server, and SQLite (or Derby or HSQLDB if you want pure Java) if it's intended to be embedded in the game client. But in that last case, I'm not sure a RDBMS is the best solution and I would go with an XML structure to spare resources.